# How to run a function on a generator concurrently with a limit on parallel jobs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, async.js

I have a generator, which generates lots of, but not infinitely many values. I want to call a high-latency function on each of them with *n* of them concurrently.

I tried to use `async.eachLimit` like this. But it prints only 3 numbers, not all of them.

```
async = require('async');

function* generator(start) {
    for (var i = start; i < start + 100; ++i) {
        yield i;
    }
}

async.eachLimit(generator(17), 3, function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

What’s the right way to achieve this?

Comment: I wrote something that might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@async-generators/parallel basically allows you to iterate over your source, then offload each to some async-process; the resulting iterator is in the order the promises complete. So, for example... you can offload each item to a separate thread (say with https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs), do some work, then yield the result. You can also limit it to only "run" N items at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I think because you're not passing in an async function it's erroring out on you

```js
'use strict';

const async = require('async');

async function* generator(start) {
  for (var i = start; i < start + 100; ++i) {
      yield i;
  }
}

(async () => {
  await async.eachLimit(generator(17), 3, async (value) => {
      console.log(value);
  });
})().catch(e => console.error);
```

Works for me;